# Polynomials in Java

Tags: java, polynomial-math

My add method works, however when I create a new `SparsePolynomial` object (at the bottom of the add method), the value of the `newSparePolynomial` changes when I debug it and I can't figure out where the extra information is coming from. Can someone help me?

Here is a copy of my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SparsePolynomial {

    private ArrayList<Polynomial> polynomialarraylist = new ArrayList<Polynomial>();

    /**
     * Constructor to get values of an arraylist of integers
     * @param arraylist that contains the  integer values used for the polynomials
     */
    public SparsePolynomial(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList)
    {
        //MODIFIDED: polynomialarraylist
        //EFFECT: constructs the arraylist of polynomials based off the arraylist of integers
        insertIntoPolynomialArray(arrayList);
    }

    /**
     * Converts the elements of the integer array into polynomials
     * @param arrayList that contains the polynomials contents
     */
    private void insertIntoPolynomialArray(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList)
    {
        //MODIFIED: polynomialarray
        //EFFECT: inputs the values of the arrayList into the polynomial array based on the position of the digits
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
        {
            Polynomial polynomial = new Polynomial(arrayList.get(i), arrayList.get(i+1));
            polynomialarraylist.add(polynomial);
            System.out.println("coef" + arrayList.get(i));
            System.out.println("degree" + arrayList.get(i+1));
            i++;
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        String result = "";
        sort();
        if (getDegree(0) ==  0) 
            return "" + getCoefficient(0);
        if (getDegree(0) ==  1) 
            return getCoefficient(0) + "x + " + getCoefficient(0);
        result =  getCoefficient(0) + "x^" + getDegree(0);

        for (int j = 1; j < polynomialarraylist.size(); j++) 
        {
            if(j > polynomialarraylist.size())
            {
                break;
            }
            if      
            (getCoefficient(j) == 0) continue;
            else if 
            (getCoefficient(j)  > 0) result = result+ " + " + ( getCoefficient(j));
            else if 
            (getCoefficient(j)  < 0) result = result+ " - " + (-getCoefficient(j));
            if(getDegree(j) == 1) result = result + "x";
            else if (getDegree(j) >  1) result = result + "x^" + getDegree(j);
        }
        return result;


    }

    /**
     * Sorts array 
     * @param array to sort
     */
    private void sort()
    {
        ArrayList<Polynomial> temp = polynomialarraylist;
        ArrayList<Polynomial> temp2 = new ArrayList<Polynomial>();
        int polydegreemain = polynomialarraylist.get(0).degree();
        temp2.add(polynomialarraylist.get(0));
        for(int i = 1; i < polynomialarraylist.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i > polynomialarraylist.size())
            {
                break;
            }
            int polydegreesecondary = polynomialarraylist.get(i).degree();

            if(polydegreemain < polydegreesecondary)
            {
                temp.set(i-1, polynomialarraylist.get(i));
                temp.set(i, temp2.get(0));
            }

        }

        polynomialarraylist = temp;
    }
    /**
     * Makes object hashable
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((polynomialarraylist == null) ? 0 : polynomialarraylist
                        .hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Checks for equality of two objects
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SparsePolynomial other = (SparsePolynomial) obj;
        if (polynomialarraylist == null) {
            if (other.polynomialarraylist != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!polynomialarraylist.equals(other.polynomialarraylist))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean equals(SparsePolynomial Sparse)
    {
        if(this == Sparse)
        {
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }

    public SparsePolynomial add(SparsePolynomial other)
    {

        ArrayList<Polynomial> thisPolynomial = createPolynomial();
        SparsePolynomial newSparsePolynomial;
        ArrayList<Polynomial> otherPolynomial = other.createPolynomial();
        Polynomial oldsum = new Polynomial();
        Polynomial newsum = new Polynomial();
        for(int i = 0; i < thisPolynomial.size();i++)
        {
            if(thisPolynomial.size() == 1)
            {
                newsum = thisPolynomial.get(i);
                oldsum = newsum;
                break;
            }
            if(i == 0)
            {
            newsum = thisPolynomial.get(i).add(thisPolynomial.get(i+1));
            oldsum = newsum;
            i++;
            }
            else
            { 
                newsum = oldsum.add(thisPolynomial.get(i));
                oldsum = newsum;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < otherPolynomial.size(); i++)
        {       
            newsum = oldsum.add(otherPolynomial.get(i));
            oldsum = newsum;
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < oldsum.degree()+1; i++)
        {
            ints.add(oldsum.coefficient(i));
            ints.add(i);
        }
        newSparsePolynomial = new SparsePolynomial(ints);

        return newSparsePolynomial;
    }

    public SparsePolynomial subtract(SparsePolynomial other)
    {
        ArrayList<Polynomial> thisPolynomial = createPolynomial();

        ArrayList<Polynomial> otherPolynomial = other.createPolynomial();

        Polynomial olddifference = new Polynomial();
        Polynomial newdifference = new Polynomial();
        for(int i = 0; i < thisPolynomial.size()+1;i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                newdifference = thisPolynomial.get(i).subtract(thisPolynomial.get(i+1));
                olddifference = newdifference;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                newdifference = olddifference.subtract(thisPolynomial.get(i));
                olddifference = newdifference;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < otherPolynomial.size(); i++)
        {

            newdifference = olddifference.add(otherPolynomial.get(i));
            olddifference = newdifference;

        }

        ArrayList<Polynomial> polyarray = createArrayListOfPolynomialsFromPolynomials(olddifference);

        ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < polyarray.size(); i++)
        {
        ints.add(polyarray.get(i).coefficient(polyarray.get(i).degree()));
        ints.add(polyarray.get(i).degree());
        }

        SparsePolynomial newSparsePolynomial = new SparsePolynomial(ints);

        return newSparsePolynomial;
    }


    private int getDegree(int index)
    {
        int degree;

        degree = polynomialarraylist.get(index).degree();

        return degree;
    }

    private int getCoefficient(int index)
    {
        int coefficient;

        coefficient = polynomialarraylist.get(index).coefficient(polynomialarraylist.get(index).degree());

        return coefficient;
    }

    private ArrayList<Polynomial> createPolynomial()
    {
        Polynomial polynomial = null;
        ArrayList<Polynomial> polynomialArray = new ArrayList<Polynomial>();
        for(int i = 0; i < polynomialarraylist.size(); i++)
        {
            polynomial = new Polynomial(getCoefficient(i), getDegree(i));
            polynomialArray.add(polynomial);        
        }
        return polynomialArray;
    }
Polynomial class

public class Polynomial {
    // Overview: ...
    private int[] terms;
    private int degree;

    // Constructors
    public Polynomial() {
        // Effects: Initializes this to be the zero polynomial
        terms = new int[1];
        degree = 0;
    }

    public Polynomial(int constant, int power) {
        // Effects: if n < 0 throws IllegalArgumentException else
        //  initializes this to be the polynomial c*x^n
        if(power < 0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Polynomial(int, int) constructor");
        }

        if(constant == 0) {
            terms = new int[1];
            degree = 0;
            return;
        }

        terms = new int[power+1];

        for(int i=0; i<power; i++) {
            terms[i] = 0;
        }

        terms[power] = constant;
        degree = power;
    }

    private Polynomial(int power) {
        terms = new int[power+1];
        degree = power;
    }

    // Methods
    public int degree() {
        // Effects: Returns the degree of this, i.e., the largest exponent
        //  with a non-zero coefficient.  Returns 0 is this is the zero polynomial
        return degree;
    }

    public int coefficient(int degree) {
        // Effects: Returns the coefficient of the term of this whose exponent is degree
        if(degree < 0 || degree > this.degree) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return terms[degree];
        }
    }

    public Polynomial subtract(Polynomial other) throws NullPointerException {
        // Effects: if other is null throws a NullPointerException else
        //  returns the Polynomial this - other
        return add(other.minus());
    }

    public Polynomial minus() {
        // Effects: Returns the polynomial - this
        Polynomial result = new Polynomial(degree);
        for(int i=0; i<=degree; i++) {
            result.terms[i] = -this.terms[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Polynomial add(Polynomial other) throws NullPointerException {
        // Effects: If other is null throws NullPointerException else
        //  returns the Polynomial this + other
        Polynomial larger, smaller;
        if (degree > other.degree){
            larger = this;
            smaller = other;
        }
        else {
            larger = other;
            smaller = this;
        }

        int newDegree = larger.degree;

        if (degree == other.degree) {
            for(int k = degree; k > 0 ; k--) {
                if (this.terms[k] + other.terms[k] != 0) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    newDegree --;
                }
            }
        }


        Polynomial newPoly = new Polynomial(newDegree);
        int i;
        for (i=0; i <= smaller.degree && i <= newDegree; i++){
            newPoly.terms[i] = smaller.terms[i] + larger.terms[i];
        }

        for(int j=i; j <= newDegree; j++) {
            newPoly.terms[j] = larger.terms[j];
        }

        return newPoly;
    }

    public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial other) throws NullPointerException {
        // Effects: If other is null throws NullPointerException else
        //  returns the Polynomial this * other
        if ((other.degree == 0 && other.terms[0] == 0) ||
                (this.degree==0 && this.terms[0] == 0)) {
                    return new Polynomial();
        }

        Polynomial newPoly = new Polynomial(degree + other.degree);

        newPoly.terms[degree + other.degree] = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<=degree; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<= other.degree; j++) {
                newPoly.terms[i+j] = newPoly.terms[i+j] + this.terms[i] * other.terms[j];
            }
        }
        return newPoly;
    }
```

Comment: Your polynomials look rather dense.

Answer (score 1):

At quick glance, looks like this is a problem

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
{
    Polynomial polynomial = new Polynomial(arrayList.get(i), arrayList.get(i+1));
    polynomialarraylist.add(polynomial);
    System.out.println("coef" + arrayList.get(i));
    System.out.println("degree" + arrayList.get(i+1));
    i++;
}
```

You're doing i++ twice here.

Also, you posted WAY too much code. No one wants to read that much. You're just lucky that, assuming this is the problem, I happened to glance at that.

Also that will throw an arrayindexoutofboundserror since you're doing .get(i+1)

Comment: looks intentional, tho i cant say i like the idea.  look at the last two lines before i++  .  it appears that even indexes are coefficients, odd are degrees (exponents of x)

Comment: no. say that when i create the final result in the new Sparepolynomial. The correct answer is present in the variable box. if you leave take the cursor off the new sparse variable for a sec and then place it is added to the answer will have more added to it.
ex: answer = 2x^7+3x^2 ----->(seconds later) 2x^7+3x^2+2x^7+3x^2 (constantly changing). this is while i am debugging and am at the end of the add method. I have debugged the code numerous times and can't find the cause of this bug.

Comment: The problem comes from when i try to send the ints Array to the Constructor. This causes the program to insert polynomials in the result. It would much help if I someone could explain to me why its doing this.

Comment: Your problem is really unclear, and you still have waaay too much code

Answer (score 0):

the constructor is set up the way it is because the get(i) gets you the coefficient and the i+1 gets you the degree from the arraylist parameter since when you call add, without those the arraylist contents would be off

THe constructor is suppose to take an Arraylist and put them inisde of an arraylist of polynomials. using the odds as the coefficient and the evens as the degrees of the polynomials.